# Brightest star in the Eastern sky 2017 in am

Tags: amateur-observing

What is the name of brightest star in the East 2am.  What does a satellite look like?

Comment: There are two questions here. But neither is asked clearly.   First you should do you own initial research, like downloading planetarium software. Next you haven't told us where or the date. You will need this when you do your research. The other question, about satellites should also be researched. There are already answers here about satellites. Please take the [tour] to read how to write effective questions.

Comment: You might try the free [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/) application to help you work out what that was (or at least to work out if it was a star or planet).